# Prevent tabkey focus change when usercontrol focused

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UserControl like following:

```
public partial class TextControlBox : UserControl
{
    public TextControlBox()
    {
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
    }
    private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Tab)
        {
            //insert tabkey into textbox
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I add the UserControl into my Mainpage.xaml which also contains other controls, the tab-key moves the focus to the next control but
I would like it to insert a tab character (\t) into my textbox instead.
How can I archive this?

I tried handling the event using e.Handled = true if the tab-key is pressed but this did not work.

Comment: Have you tried adding these to your code: ```textBox.AcceptsTab = true; ``` and ```textBox.Multiline = true;``` If both these properties are true for the text box, then a keypress event should not be necessary for the textbox to accept a tab input

Comment: Oh sorry I did not mention, that I have a custom textbox, made from scratch. So neither property exists. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you will need to use [UIElement.KeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown?view=winrt-22621) instead of the [CoreWindow.KeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown?view=winrt-22621). CoreWindow.KeyDown Event will not raise when the Tab key is pressed because it's a system key.

Here is the code that I'm using and it works:

```
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += MyUserControl1_KeyDown;
    }

    private void MyUserControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //insert tabkey into textbox
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("MyUserControl1_KeyDown");
    }
```

Comment: I think your code totally works. But I have the problem, that my UserControl doesn't trigger any events. Only events on controls inside of the UserControl are getting triggered. That's really weird. Do you know a fix for that

Comment: @FrozenAssassine Do you mean the event of the usercontrol itself won't be triggered? But controls inside the usercontrol could trigger events correctly?

Comment: Yeah you are right

Comment: @FrozenAssassine I'm testing just with a TextBox in the UserControl and I can't reprodue the issue you mentioned. Could you please update your question and share more code that could reproduce this behavior in a blank project?

Comment: Ok, I finally got it working and it was so simple. All I missed was IsTabStop="True". Thank you for your time.